# ROR Active Record not save data correcty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, simple-form-for

Hi guys i have a problem and i dont' know how to solve it, i'm really new on the ROR's world.

preamble : **each municiplaty has many itinerary**, so :

**1)** i've **created the itinerary table** with this migration :

```
class CreateItineraries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :itineraries do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :json
      t.integer :muncipality_id
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :published, :default => true, :null => false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**2)** i've **added the municipality_id reference to the itineraries table**, with this migration :

```
class AddMunicipalityIdToItineraries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :itineraries, :municipality, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**3)** i've **created another table for the translations of itineraries** :

```
class AddTranslationTablesForItineraries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Itinerary.create_translation_table!({
                                                  :title => :string
                                              }, {
                                                  :migrate_data => true
                                              })
  end

  def down
    add_column :itineraries, :title, :string
    Itinerary.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
  end
end
```

now, the problem is when i try to save the data from the relative simple_form, **it save the itinerary's title only in the translations table**, why?!

here the code of the simple_form :

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @municipality, @itinerary], url: @url, :html => {:class => ''} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'application/translation_form_heading' %>
    # ...
    <%= f.input :title, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :description, label: 'description', :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => {ckeditor: {toolbar: get_toolbar('default')},:rows => 15} %>
    <%= f.input :json, required: true, label: 'GeoJSON', as: :text, :input_html => {:rows => 15} %>

    # ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save itinerary</button>    
<% end %>
```

maybe it's a newbie question, but i don'r really know how to solve it, thank you!

edit : here the code of the **itinerariesController** :

```
class Admin::ItinerariesController < InheritedResources::Base
  layout 'admin'
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  before_filter :set_page_title
  load_and_authorize_resource
  actions :all, :except => [:show]

  belongs_to :municipality

  def index
    @itineraries = Itinerary.ordered
  end

  def new
    @url = admin_municipality_itineraries_path(params[:municipality_id])
    new!
  end

  def edit
    @url = admin_municipality_itinerary_path(params[:municipality_id], params[:id])
    edit!
  end

  def update
    unless params[:translate_to].blank?
      I18n.with_locale(params[:translate_to]) {
        update!
      }
    else
      update!
    end
  end

  def set_page_title
    @page_title = PointOfInterest.model_name.human(:count => 2).titleize
  end

  def create
    create! {
      admin_municipality_itineraries_path
    }
  end

  private
  def permitted_params
    params.permit(:itinerary => [:id, :title, :json,:description, :municipality_id] )
  end

end
```

Comment: can you share controller code where you creating this.?

Comment: Do you mean the itinerrary controller?

Comment: The first thing that seems odd is that only the `title` is translated. Maybe `description` also needs to be translated (i.e. migrated the same way you did for `title`).

Comment: I don't see why you are specifying the url separately. Just declare the routes properly and rails will give the correct url when you use  `simple_form_for [:admin, @municipality, @itinerary]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update this one in controller

```
 private 
 def permitted_params  
   params.permit(:itinerary => [:id, :title, :description, :municipality_id, :json] ) 
 end
```

You need to permit JSON value in params always at the end

Comment: def edit
    @url = admin_municipality_itinerary_path(params[:municipality_id], params[:id])
    edit!
  end, please share edit! code, if you have created any concern file for this one?, I am not getting what your doing here?

Comment: in my edit func i defined the url : "@url = admin_municipality_itinerary_path(params[:municipality_id], params[:id])"
then i called "edit!"

Comment: I think your controller code has some mistake, Please read this before https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-controllers.htm

Comment: yes but i can't find a solution... do you have an idea?